# Facebook Native in feed ads are overlapping to each other in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, facebook-audience-network, native-ads

I have an app which has Recyclerview and I want to put some facebook Native ads in between list items, like every 5 list items 1 native ad will be shown. everything is working perfectly but main problem is when I scroll down adChoice icon is being doubled and on scrolling up also adChoice icons are getting doubled. It seems that ads are overlapping to the previous one.

[SCREENSHOT](https://res.cloudinary.com/ravi40/image/upload/v1532241837/my_json/ads_overlapping_jpg.jpg)

Any suggestion will help me a lot. Here is the all source code and the [official facebook audience network native ad code sample](https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network/tree/master/samples/android/RCPY).

***dependency***

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

***content_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewHead"
                android:text="Heading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDesc"
                android:text="Description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

***ads_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adChoicesContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.facebook.ads.AdIconView
            android:id="@+id/adIconView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAdTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                tools:text="Ad Title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAdBody"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lines="3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                tools:text="This is an ad description."/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.facebook.ads.MediaView
        android:id="@+id/mediaView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sponsored_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCTA"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:text="Install Now"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***ContentModel.java***

```
package com.example.my_demo_app.fb_in-feed_ad;

public class ContentModel {

    String head, des;

    public ContentModel(String head, String des) {
        this.head = head;
        this.des = des;
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public String getDes() {
        return des;
    }
}
```

***MyAdapter.java***

```
package com.example.my_demo_app.fb_in-feed_ad;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.ads.Ad;
import com.facebook.ads.AdChoicesView;
import com.facebook.ads.AdIconView;
import com.facebook.ads.MediaView;
import com.facebook.ads.NativeAd;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
    public static final int AD_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    private final List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;
    private final Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<Object> recyclerViewItems, Context context) {
        this.mRecyclerViewItems = recyclerViewItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //--------------------getItemViewType

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Object recyclerViewItem = mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
        if (recyclerViewItem instanceof ContentModel) {
            return MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
        } else if (recyclerViewItem instanceof Ad) {
            return AD_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }


    //--------------------getItemCount

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecyclerViewItems.size();
    }

    //--------------------onCreateViewHolder

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if (viewType==MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE){
            View menuItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_layout, parent, false);
            return new MenuItemHolder(menuItemView);
        }else if (viewType==AD_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE){
            View adItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_layout, parent, false);
            return new AdHolder(adItemView);
        }
        return null;
    }

    //--------------------onBindViewHolder

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

        if (itemType==MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE){
            MenuItemHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemHolder) holder;
            ContentModel contentModel = (ContentModel) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);
            menuItemHolder.txtH.setText(contentModel.getHead());
            menuItemHolder.txtD.setText(contentModel.getDes());
        }else if (itemType==AD_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE){

            AdHolder nativeAdViewHolder = (AdHolder) holder;
            NativeAd nativeAd = (NativeAd) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

            AdIconView adIconView = nativeAdViewHolder.adIconView;
            TextView tvAdTitle = nativeAdViewHolder.tvAdTitle;
            TextView tvAdBody = nativeAdViewHolder.tvAdBody;
            Button btnCTA = nativeAdViewHolder.btnCTA;
            LinearLayout adChoicesContainer = nativeAdViewHolder.adChoicesContainer;
            MediaView mediaView = nativeAdViewHolder.mediaView;
            TextView sponsorLabel = nativeAdViewHolder.sponsorLabel;

            tvAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiserName());
            tvAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBodyText());
            btnCTA.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
            sponsorLabel.setText(nativeAd.getSponsoredTranslation());

            AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);
            adChoicesContainer.addView(adChoicesView);

            List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
            clickableViews.add(btnCTA);
            clickableViews.add(mediaView);
            nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(nativeAdViewHolder.container, mediaView, adIconView, clickableViews);

        }
    }

    //--------------------MenuItemHolder

    public class MenuItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView txtH, txtD;

        public MenuItemHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtH = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            txtD = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        }
    }

    //--------------------AdHolder

    public class AdHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        AdIconView adIconView;
        TextView tvAdTitle;
        TextView tvAdBody;
        Button btnCTA;
        View container;
        TextView sponsorLabel;
        LinearLayout adChoicesContainer;
        MediaView mediaView;

        AdHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.container = itemView;
            adIconView = (AdIconView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.adIconView);
            tvAdTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAdTitle);
            tvAdBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAdBody);
            btnCTA = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCTA);
            adChoicesContainer = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.adChoicesContainer);
            mediaView = (MediaView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mediaView);
            sponsorLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sponsored_label);
        }
    }
}
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.my_demo_app.fb_in-feed_ad;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.facebook.ads.Ad;
import com.facebook.ads.AdError;
import com.facebook.ads.NativeAd;
import com.facebook.ads.NativeAdListener;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_DATA = "https://res.cloudinary.com/ravi40/raw/upload/v1532239134/my_json/heroes_list.json";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_id);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();

        //--------------------Native Ad

        NativeAd nativeAd = new NativeAd(getApplicationContext(), "IMG_16_9_LINK#YOUR_FACEBOOK_NATIVE_AD_PLACEMENT_ID_WILL_GOES_HERE");  // IMG_16_9_LINK# denote only testing purpose
        nativeAd.setAdListener(new NativeAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMediaDownloaded(Ad ad) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

                for (int i=4; i<mRecyclerViewItems.size()+4; i+=5)
                mRecyclerViewItems.add(i, ad);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {

            }
        });

        nativeAd.loadAd();

        loadRecyclerViewData();
    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("heroes");
                            for (int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                ContentModel item = new ContentModel(
                                        o.getString("name"),
                                        o.getString("about")
                                );
                                mRecyclerViewItems.add(item);
                            }

                            adapter = new MyAdapter(mRecyclerViewItems, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad** are getting overlapped when adding in the container. The solution is to clear the container before adding the ads again.

For example:

```
AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(context, nativeAd, true);

// Clear the container.
adChoicesContainer.removeAllViews()

adChoicesContainer.addView(adChoicesView);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, It was driving me crazy